# Is there any way to define a struct/enum in source file but give interface in header file

Tags: c, struct, header-files

Is there any way to hide the structure/ enum in the source file (.c) and only provide its interface in the header file (.h)?

Comment: What is the “interface” of a structure? If you mean can you provide its definition (the names and types of its members, and the sequence they are in) in a source file but not in a header, the answer is yes, as long as clients only use pointers to the structure. You would need to supply routines that allocate, initialize, free, and otherwise work with the structures, as the clients can do none of that without the definitions. For enumerations, no, an enumeration must be defined before it can be used at all.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Thank you.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's that's what you're looking for, but you could define a struct in the header file of size 512 by just having a `char[512]` within the structure.

You could define a completely different structure which is also of same total size, but different members. Then the users of the structure could allocate and free it, but you'd have to be very careful that your structure being the right number of bytes.

Typically if you want to hide entire implementation, you'd just return a void pointer and handle allocation, but you could do:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int version;
    char name [28] ;
    char hidden[480];
};
```

Then use those hidden bytes as you wish.